# copy object pointer into dynamic object array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, malloc

I am working with a class I created that has a function addClass which allow the user to add A an Instance of Class to a dynamically allocated array.

Here is the code of the class and a simple test:

**Class.h Listing**

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

#include<iostream>

class Class {
public:
    Class(std::string text);
    Class(const Class& orig);
    virtual ~Class();
    Class(std::string text, Class * name, int size);
    std::string toString();
    void addClass(Class * name, int size = 1);
    Class getClass(int index);
private:
    Class * classArray;
    std::string value;
    int size;

};

#endif  /* CLASS_H */
```

**Class.c Listing**

```
#include "Class.h"
#include <cstdlib>


Class::Class(std::string text) {
    classArray = NULL;
    value = text;
    size = 0;
}

Class::Class(const Class& orig) {/*...*/}

Class::~Class() {}

Class::Class(std::string text, Class * name, int size){
    value = text;
    this->size = size;
    if(size == 1)
        classArray = name;
    else{
        int i;
        classArray = (Class*)malloc(size*sizeof(Class));
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
            classArray[i] = name[i];
        }
    }
}

std::string Class::toString(){
    return value;
}

void Class::addClass(Class * name, int size){
    int i;
    Class * tmp = (Class*)malloc((this->size+size)*sizeof(Class));
    for(i = 0; i < this->size-1; i++){
        tmp[i] = classArray[i];
    }
    if(size == 1)
        tmp[size-1] = name[0];//assignement method is the problem!!!??
    else{
        for(i = this->size; i < this->size+size-1; i++){
            tmp[i] = name[i];
        }
    }
    this->size += size;
    free(classArray);
    classArray = tmp;
}

Class Class::getClass(int index){
    return classArray[index];
}
```

**test.c Listing**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Class.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Class * objectA = new Class("objectA");
    Class * objectB = new Class("objectB");

    cout << objectA->toString() << endl;

    objectA->addClass(objectB);
    //never gets here :'(
    cout << objectA->toString() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the test never gets past the objectA->addClass(objectB) instruction. I tried to debug and what I found was that the problem comes from the assignement instruction of the addClass() method. I also tried memcpy it didn't work. Does anyone have a solution for this please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your code you defined a custom copy constructor `Class(const Class&)` for your class, but you seem *not* having defined a *copy assignment operator* `Class& operator=(const Class&)`. Note that in your code you use copy assignment (`operator=`) to make copies of your class, but you don't have a proper implementation of it.

Moreover, in C++ you should prefer using `new[]`/`delete[]` to C's `malloc()`/`free()`, and even better just use **`std::vector`** container for arrays.

You can also have a `std::vector< SomeSmartPointer >` (e.g. `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>>`, or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>>`). In general, consider `std::vector` of some *smart pointer*, but don't use a `std::vector` of *owning raw* pointers (`std::vector<SomeClass*>`).

Comment: +1 because your answer is way more complete than [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072111/copy-object-pointer-into-dynamic-object-array#answer-19072163) too bad I saw your answer after!

Comment: @PaikuHan: You should mark as "answer" the _best_ answer (whoever is the author of it, I'm speaking in general, not just for this particular case). You can change the marked answer.

Comment: sorry I guess your right I was being egocentric. StackOverflow being a community the best answer should not be the one that helped me (with a little search from me) but the one that will help next programmers in the same situation (with no need to search for other missing part of a solution)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use malloc on C++ objects, use new and new[] and delete and delete[]. The problem with malloc in C++ is that it doesn't call the constructors for your objects, and free doesn't call the destructors. new, new[], delete and delete[] do. You get a crash because you are assigning to unconstructed objects and you get that because you didn't use new.

Not saying that's the only problem with your code, but it's the obvious one.

Comment: That's the tricky answer I actually was looking forward to. I should add like Mr.C64 (answer below) that overloading the assignement operator will be necessary (in my code) for this to work properly.

Comment: moreover the default constructor is necessary it seems to perform a new[] operation

Answer (score 2):

A basic solution is to prefer `new` and `delete` over `malloc` and `free`. A much better solution is to use a standard container such as `std::vector` to hold the elements at `Class::addClass()`. Let the computer take care of all that memory management; you will be saving a lot of development and debugging time.

Comment: Hi, I thought of that already, in a matter of fact I think I'am going to use that solution since it seems to be the only best option. But I really do want to know how to solve this without std::vector just so I know more about how C/C++ work.

Comment: You may explore the structure of the `vector` standard header, this will help you understand how `new` and `delete` are used in C++, how they are used as opposed to `malloc` and `free`, and also the cases in which the latter are used. Check out the `list` standard header as well.